# Attaching delegates to webBrowser html elements

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, lambda

I am working on a windows form UserControl to render and interact with some HTML using the webBrowser control. Part of the content are some radio buttons that I need to capture click events from within my control. So in the DocumentCompleted event of the webBrowser I am attaching an onClick event to the radio buttons. All of this seems to work until I click on one of the radio buttons, it seems that only the final radio button is actually having the event attached, even though I have stepped through the code and the delegate is being attached for each radio button.

This is the lambda I am using to attach the delegate to the HtmlElement.

```
void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
     {
         el.AttachEventHandler("onclick", (sender1, e1) => clickEventHandler(el, EventArgs.Empty));
     }
}

public void clickEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Guid answerId;
    var he = (HtmlElement)sender;
    if (Guid.TryParse(he.Id, out answerId))
        if (AnswerSelected != null)
            AnswerSelected(answerId);
 }
```

Delegate and event for AnswerSelected

```
public delegate void HtmlControlAnswerEventHandler(Guid answerId);
public event HtmlControlAnswerEventHandler AnswerSelected;
```

Input button string.

```
<input type=radio id="{0}" name="answer" value="{1}" />
```

Comment: When you say `testEventHandler` do you really mean `clickEventHandler`?

Comment: Cool, what is `AnswerSelected`?

Comment: AnswerSelected is another event that is fired to notify the form that contains this control of the answer selected and the answers id.

Comment: Is it maybe assigning your event handler to radio button one, then re-assigning it to radio button two, then re-assigning it to radio button three? Have you tried explicitly assigning each radio button to a seperate event handler, for testing purposes?

Comment: No, but I will try that right now.

Comment: No the result is the same, even though the other event handlers are being triggered, it must be the sender1 parameter.

Comment: Are all of your radio buttons called `input`?

Comment: Ah ok, my HTML is pretty poor, was looking at this from the C# angle but I am out of ideas! Apologies!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14413/discussion-between-siegeon-and-jmk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that when using lambdas like this the variable used to reference the object is lost. If I attach the events this way

```
void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
     {
         el.AttachEventHandler("onclick", (sender1, e1) => clickEventHandler(el, EventArgs.Empty));
     }
}
```

then only the last attached event is valid.

When I attach the events this way

```
private void AttachClickEventToInputs()
{
      var htmlElements = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
      for (int i = 0; i < htmlElements.Count; i++)
      {
          htmlElements[i].AttachEventHandler("onclick", (sender1, e1) => clickEventHandler(htmlElements[i], EventArgs.Empty));
      }
 }
```

There is an issue with the inder i becoming greater then the number of elements (this stumps me.)

However if I attach the events this way

```
private void AttachClickEventToInputs()
{
     var htmlElements = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
     for (int i = 0; i < htmlElements.Count; i++)
     {
          HtmlElement el = htmlElements[i];
          el.AttachEventHandler("onclick", (sender1, e1) => clickEventHandler(el, EventArgs.Empty));
     }
}
```

then everything works as intended. I am not completly sure why this works, other then maybe we need a hard reference to the object when attaching delegates?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the the scope of the `el` variable. At the time the delegate is evaluated, the loop has completed and `el` is holds the value of the last list item. You can resolve this by assigning `el` to a variable within the loop.

```
void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     foreach (HtmlElement _el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
     {
         HtmlElement el = _el;
         el.AttachEventHandler("onclick", (sender1, e1) => clickEventHandler(el, EventArgs.Empty));
     }
}
```